# IIS 7.5 - SSL 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: ssl, certificate, iis-7.5, httpforbiddenhandler

I've developed a simple ASP.NET application. In my test page i have this code:

> protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
>       {
>           Response.Write(Request.ClientCertificate.SerialNumber);
>       }

I've installed **IIS Client Certificate Mapping Authentication** and **Client Certificate Mapping Authentication**

1. I've enabled Https on IIS.
2. I've binded 443 with my own certificate
3. i've also enabled SSL and set Require SSL

When i try it on my local machine , all works and i can see smartcard logon window, i can see my certificate

After this i try all this on a remote Server (Virtual machine with Windows 2008 R2 Std SP1 64bit). I've done all previous step but when i try to navigate to my remote https url i receive

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

Then i've started to find a solution , and i'm focused on the certificate. I've tried various certificates
but no way to resolve.

how do I set the authentication?
what can i set or review?

Any one can give me some help?

> UPDATE

I've created a **Self-Signed Certificate on IIS** and now when i access on site, i can view Smartcard Logon Windows. I choice certificate and insert Password, after i receive 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. The Error in Log il 403.16

Comment: Maybe Technet forum could know the answer for your question, or you could ask from there as well :-) https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-us/home?category=sqlserver

Comment: Here is the Windows Server URL: http://blogs.technet.com/b/windowsserver/  the previous one was for SQL Server (sorry)